# Error in updating the file

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

edit.php

```
                        <?php
                        $nameErr = $emailErr = $fileToUploadErr = $fileToUploadErrr = $fileToUploadErrrr = $fileToUploadErrrrr = $fileToUploadErrrrrr = "";
                        $file= $name = $email = $filename  = "";

                        include_once 'connect.php';
                        $id = $_GET['id'];
                        $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select * from `users` where userid ='$id'");
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

                        //set a default variable to hold the original value if $_POST is not triggered
                        $name = $row['name'];

                        $email = $row['email'];


                        $filename= $row['filename'];

                            // checking weather the form has been submitted before performing the update query
                        if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

                            //Name Section    
                            if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                                $nameErr = "Name is required";
                            } else {
                                $name = $_POST["name"];
                              // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                                if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $name)) {
                                    $nameErr = "Only letters allowed no blank space";
                                }
                            }

                            //E-mail Section
                            if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                                $emailErr = "Email is required";
                            } else {
                                $email = $_POST["email"];
                            // check if e-mail address is well-formed
                                if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                                    $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
                                }
                            }


                            //UPLOAD FILE
                            $uploaddir = 'upload/';
                            $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['filename']['name']);
                            $imageFileType = pathinfo($uploadfile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                            if ($_FILES['filename']['name'] != '') {  

                                // Check if file already exists
                                if (file_exists($uploadfile)) {
                                    $fileToUploadErrrrrr = "Sorry, file already exists.";
                                }

                                if ($imageFileType != "dotx" && $imageFileType != "pdf" && $imageFileType != "txt") {
                                    $fileToUploadErr = "Sorry, only Word,pdf,text files are allowed.";
                                } 
                                else {

                                    $uploaded = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
                                    if ($uploaded) {
                                        $file = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
                                    } else {
                                        $file = $filename;
                                    }
                                }
                            }  



                            if ($nameErr == "" && $emailErr == "" && $fileToUploadErr == "" && $fileToUploadErrr == "" && $fileToUploadErrrr == "" && $fileToUploadErrrrr == "" && $fileToUploadErrrrrr == "") {
                                $check = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' and userid !='$id'";
                                $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli, $check);
                                $da = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
                                if ($da > 0) {
                                    echo "email Already in Exists";
                                } else 
                                {
                                    if($file=="" || $filename != NULL)
                                    {
                                        $sql = "update `users` set name='$name', email='$email' where userid ='$id'";
                                        if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
                                            echo "Record updated successfully";
                                        } else {
                                            echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error(mysqli_query);
                                        }
                                        mysqli_close($mysqli);
                                    }
                                    else{

                                        $sql = "update `users` set name='$name',  email='$email', filename='$file' where userid ='$id'";
                                        if($filename != NULL):
                                        $target = "upload/".$filename;
                                        unlink($target);
                                        endif;
                                        if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
                                            echo "Record updated successfully";
                                        } else {
                                            echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error(mysqli_query);
                                        }
                                        mysqli_close($mysqli);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        ?>


                        <!DOCTYPE html>
                        <html>
                        <head>
                            <style>
                                            .error {
                                                color:red;
                                            }

                                            .button {
                                                background-color: #4CAF50;
                                                border: none;
                                                color: white;
                                                padding: 10px 25px;
                                                text-align: center;
                                                text-decoration: none;
                                                display: inline-block;
                                                font-size: 16px;
                                                margin: 4px 2px;
                                                cursor: pointer;
                                            }
                                            .div1 {
                                               /* background-color: #ff80b3;*/
                                                margin-top: -19px;
                                                margin-bottom: -25px;
                                                margin-left: -19px; 
                                            }

                                            .copy {
                                                border-radius: 4px;
                                                padding: 6px 20px;
                                               border-style: ridge;
                                            }

                                            .copy1{
                                                 border-radius: 4px;
                                                 padding: 6px 28px;
                                                 border-style: ridge;
                                            }

                                            .copy2{
                                                 border-radius: 4px;
                                                 padding: 4px 2px;

                                            }
                            </style>
                        </head>
            <body style="background-color: #ff80b3">

                    <div style="padding-left: 250px" class="div1">
                    <br><br><br><br>
                    <h2 style="color:#1aff1a">EDIT :</h2>

                        <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?= $id ?>"/>
                            <label style="color:000000">Name:</label><input class= "copy" style="margin-left: 52px" type="text" value="<?= $name ?>" name="name">
                            <span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr; ?></span>
                            <br><br>



                            <label style="color:000000">E-mail:</label><input type="text" class= "copy" style="margin-left: 48px"  value="<?= $email ?>" name="email">
                            <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></span>
                            <br><br>



                            <label style="color:000000">UPLOAD FILE : </label><input type="file" style="width:180px;height:100px;padding:10px;" value="<?= $filename ?>" name="filename" >

                            <br>
                            <span class="error"><?php echo $fileToUploadErr; ?></span>
                            <span class="error"><?php echo $fileToUploadErrrr; ?></span>
                            <span class="error"><?php echo $fileToUploadErrrrr; ?></span>
                            <span class="error"><br><?php echo $fileToUploadErrrrrr; ?></span>
                            <br>

                            <input type="submit" class="button" name="update" value="Update"> 
                            <a href="pannel.php">Back</a>
                        </form>

                    </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

I have created a php edit form where i want to edit my record, 
all the record are getting updated but when i try to update the attachment 
files its not getting updated but instead when i try to update the files 
the files are getting stored in the upload folder, i have tried with 
the above code, but its not working please can any one tel me where im 
going wrong.

Comment: i can't seem to understand your code, can you break it into sections

Answer (score 0):

The input tag cannot contain value attribute you need to remove it.It should be like below

```
<label style="color:000000">UPLOAD FILE : </label><input type="file" style="width:180px;height:100px;padding:10px;"  name="filename" >
```

Comment: sir that is not what i wanted

Comment: Check for the value of $file by echo or print_r bcz you said the file is getting uploaded so it is not getting inserted in the db i believe